# Скрыть GET запрос в адресной строке как?

Tags: php, .htaccess

На странице
site.com/?q=bmw

Есть доп подсказки:

site.com/?q=bmw+i8&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVjfLW3NL2AhVsmIsKHRQyB3UQ1QJ6BAgBEAE

site.com/?q=bmw+x5&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVjfLW3NL2AhVsmIsKHRQyB3UQ1QJ6BAgBEAE

Получается дубли надо убрать

&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVjfLW3NL2AhVsmIsKHRQyB3UQ1QJ6BAgBEAE

чтобы было

site.com/?q=bmw+x5

статичный только &sa=X&ved=

Этот get параметр меняется с каждым обновлением страницы

2ahUKEwiVjfLW3NL2AhVsmIsKHRQyB3UQ1QJ6BAgBEAE

Как решить вопрос?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: можете запросить данные аяксом, можете запихать в куки, можете в доп.заголовки,  можете сохранить в сессии

Answer (score 0):

скрыть запросы в адресной строке можно только через POST запрос. А через GET невозможно

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).